# WKWebview with the new iOS13 modal crash when a file picker is invoked

Tags: ios, wkwebview, uipopovercontroller, ios13

I have a webview in a modal view controller on iOS13.
When the user tries to upload an image to the webview, it crashes.

This is the exception I'm getting:

> 2019-09-30 17:50:10.676940+0900 Engage[988:157733] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your
>   application has presented a UIDocumentMenuViewController
>   (). In its current trait
>   environment, the modalPresentationStyle of a
>   UIDocumentMenuViewController with this style is
>   UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for
>   this popover through the view controller's
>   popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView
>   and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known
>   when you present the view controller, you may provide it in the
>   UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method
>   -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18926c98c 0x188f950a4 0x18cb898a8 0x18cb939b4 0x18cb914f8 0x18d283b98 0x18d2737c0 0x18d2a3594
>   0x1891e9c48 0x1891e4b34 0x1891e5100 0x1891e48bc 0x193050328
>   0x18d27a6d4 0x1002e6de4 0x18906f460) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

I'm not sure where could I set this delegate...

I made a sample project: https://github.com/ntnmrndn/WKUploadFormCrash
And filled a bug report to Apple

Comment: Do you have any updates on that bug report? Is it plausible Apple will fix this in iOS 14?

Comment: @roxanneM look at the accepted answer for a fix!

Comment: Yes, I can see that :) I'm just wondering about the Apple's response on this. Do they admit it as their bug and plan to fix it in the future?

Comment: I closed the radar after apple asked for more info (they had everything) and I found this answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As @jshapy8 correctly stated, you need to override the `present()` method and setting the `.sourceView`/`.sourceFrame`/`.barButtonItem` manually.
But you need to keep in mind that in case the `UIViewController` that holds the `WkWebView` is presented by a `UINavigationController`, the `UINavigationController` is responsible for presenting other `UIViewController`.

Unless you are on an iPad.

So in fact you need to override the `present()` method in your `UINavigationController` as well as in the `UIViewController` which holds the `WkWebView`.

In the example below, the `UIViewController` which holds the `WkWebView` is called `WebVC`.

In your `UINavigationController` you need to add:

```
  override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    if let webVC = viewControllers.filter({ $0 is WebVC }).first as? WebVC {
      webVC.setUIDocumentMenuViewControllerSoureViewsIfNeeded(viewControllerToPresent)
    }
    super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
  }
```

And in your `WebVC` you need to add:

```
  override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    setUIDocumentMenuViewControllerSoureViewsIfNeeded(viewControllerToPresent)
    super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
  }

  func setUIDocumentMenuViewControllerSoureViewsIfNeeded(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController) {
    if #available(iOS 13, *), viewControllerToPresent is UIDocumentMenuViewController && UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
      // Prevent the app from crashing if the WKWebView decides to present a UIDocumentMenuViewController while it self is presented modally.
      viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = webView
      viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: webView.center.x, y: webView.center.y, width: 1, height: 1)
    }
  }
```

So you can use the new iOS 13 modal presentation style and upload files without crashing

Edit:
This crashing behavior seems to be (another) iOS 13 bug, because this is only a problem on iPhones not on iPads (just tested it on iPads with iOS 12 & 13.
It kinda looks like the apple engineers simply forgot that in case the `WKWebView` is presented with their new modal presentation style, the `UIDocumentMenuViewController` is presented with `UIModalPresentationPopover` style, even on phones, which was until iOS 13 simply not the case.

I updated my code so now it sets the `.sourceView`/`.sourceFrame`/`.barButtonItem` only for phone types, because tablet types will be handled by iOS it self correctly.

Comment: I am using SwiftUI and the WKWebView is embedded inside a UIViewController inside a UIViewControllerRepresentable. When I add the override function present  is not called and the application continues crashing. I have tested the function by presenting manually another view controller and at that point it gets called. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Is the UIViewController which holds the WKWebView presented by a UINavigationController? If so, try to override the present method in that UINavigationController as well.
But since I never tried to use UISwift to this point, my knowledge about this is very limited.

Comment: You can use the following to remove the deprecation warning:

```
        if #available(iOS 13, *),
             viewControllerToPresent is UIDocumentMenuViewController,               // Using NSClassFromString to remove compiler's deprecation warning for `UIDocumentMenuViewController`.
             UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {               let menuViewControllerClass = NSClassFromString("UIDocumentMenuViewController"),
             viewControllerToPresent.isKind(of: menuViewControllerClass),
             UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
         {
```

Comment: @JulioBailon Hey did you find any solution I am also stuck in SwiftUI for WKWebView filepicker crash.

Comment: @JitendraGaur I decide to use a different presentation (full screen) for the web view in order to be able to present the picker.

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered a similar crash.

You may fix it by setting modalPresentationStyle to `.fullScreen`.

Comment: I filled a bug report to apple, I hope we can find a better way.

Comment: Make sure you set `fullScreen` for navigation controller if you have.

Comment: Where are we to set this `modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullScreen`? If it is applied to the view controller containing the `WKWebView` then the view controller itself takes up the full screen and does not use the new iOS 13 default of `.pageSheet`.

Comment: @Kevin_TA I used it for UINavigationViewController. It worked.

Comment: accepted answer is a hack. This is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

### Details

- Swift 5.1, Xcode 11.2.1

### Solution

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

protocol WebViewTapGestureRecognizable {
    var lastWebViewTapPosition: CGPoint { get }
}

extension WebViewTapGestureRecognizable where Self: UIViewController {
    func prepareForPresent(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController) {
         if viewControllerToPresent is UIDocumentMenuViewController || viewControllerToPresent is UIDocumentPickerViewController,
            UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone,
            let popoverPresentationController = viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController {
                popoverPresentationController.sourceView = view
                let origin = (self as WebViewTapGestureRecognizable).lastWebViewTapPosition
                popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(origin: origin, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        }
    }
}

class WebView: WKWebView {
    private(set) var lastWebViewTapPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    override init(frame: CGRect, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration) {
        super.init(frame: frame, configuration: configuration)
        setupGestureRecognizer()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: coder) }
}

extension WebView: WebViewTapGestureRecognizable, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                            shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    @objc func webViewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        lastWebViewTapPosition = sender.location(in: superview ?? self)
    }

    private func setupGestureRecognizer() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(webViewTapped(_:)) )
        tapGesture.delegate = self
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
}
```

### Usage

> For **UIViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private weak var webView: WebView!
}

extension ViewController: WebViewTapGestureRecognizable {
    var lastWebViewTapPosition: CGPoint { return webView.lastWebViewTapPosition }
    override open func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.prepareForPresent(viewControllerToPresent)
        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

> For **NavigationController**

```
import UIKit

class NavigationController: UINavigationController {}

extension NavigationController: WebViewTapGestureRecognizable {
    var lastWebViewTapPosition: CGPoint { return (visibleViewController as? WebViewTapGestureRecognizable)?.lastWebViewTapPosition ?? .zero }
    override open func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.prepareForPresent(viewControllerToPresent)
        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

### Full sample

> Do not forget to **paste here the solution code**

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        var button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Present VC", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTouchedUpInside1), for: .touchUpInside)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)

        button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Present NavVC", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTouchedUpInside2), for: .touchUpInside)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func buttonTouchedUpInside1() {
        present(ViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func buttonTouchedUpInside2() {
        present(NavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController()), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private weak var webView: WebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createWebView()
    }

    private func createWebView() {
        let webView = WebView(frame: .zero,
                              configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        view.addSubview(webView)
        self.webView = webView
        //webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        let urlString = "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_file"
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!))
    }
}

extension ViewController: WebViewTapGestureRecognizable {
    var lastWebViewTapPosition: CGPoint { return webView.lastWebViewTapPosition }
    override open func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.prepareForPresent(viewControllerToPresent)
        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


import UIKit

class NavigationController: UINavigationController {}

extension NavigationController: WebViewTapGestureRecognizable {
    var lastWebViewTapPosition: CGPoint { return (visibleViewController as? WebViewTapGestureRecognizable)?.lastWebViewTapPosition ?? .zero }
    override open func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.prepareForPresent(viewControllerToPresent)
        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

### Results

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, UIKit is deciding that the `UIDocumentMenuController` should be a popover, and therefore it expects either the `sourceView` and `sourceFrame` or the `barButtonItem` of that popover to be set (the crash is precisely because those *haven't* been set).

If you want to keep the iOS 13 modal presentation style without having to revert to just using `.fullScreen`, in the view controller which embeds the `WKWebView` you can override `present` to grab a reference to the `UIDocumentMenuViewController` and set properties on its `popoverPresentationController`:

```swift
class WebViewController: UIViewController {
    override open func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        if #available(iOS 13, *), viewControllerToPresent is UIDocumentMenuViewController {
            viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = // reference to a bar button item you want to present the popover from
            // OR
            viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = // whatever view you want to present the popover from
            viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController?.sourceFrame = // that view's frame
        }

        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: `open func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)` does not get called.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here : https://medium.com/swlh/popover-menu-over-cards-containing-webkit-views-on-ios-13-a16705aff8af. Thanks to the author.

I just add these two functions to avoid the crash.

```
override open func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
      if #available(iOS 13, *), viewControllerToPresent is UIDocumentMenuViewController {
        viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
      }
      super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }

func prepareForPopoverPresentation(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
      popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
    }
```

Then you have to set the position of your popover.